# Two domains, one site how to manage civicontribute?

Tags: civicontribute, multisite

Civicontribute post-transaction response page always reverts to primary domain. How can I force it to stick with the original domain?

Comment: What Civi version and CMS are you using?

Comment: In addition to Allen's question - what is your multi-site configuration?  E.g. Drupal multi-site is different from Drupal with Domain Access, but both can support a CiviCRM multi-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation

Plus Domain Access Module (Drupal) got me 90% of the way there - however no matter what I try, contribution pages and event pages auto-generate their page links with the primary domain.

Comment: On a multisite using Domain, if I am at Site B to visit the contribution page, i remain at Site B for the confirmation and Thank You pages. Perhaps something amiss in your civicrm.settings.php?